# Given N, generate sequence of random numbers from 0 to N - 1 with no repetitions

Tags: c#, comparative-review, shuffle

Problem statement:
Given an integer n, write a function to return an array of size n, containing each of the numbers from 0 to n-1 in a random order. The numbers may not repeat and each number must show up exactly once.

Solution # 1:
Generate an ordered array then shuffle it

```
private static int[] Shuffle(int n)
{
    var a = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        var j = random.Next(0, i);
        Swap(a, i, j);
    }
    return a;
}

private static void Swap(int[] a, int i, int j)
{
    var temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

Solution # 2:
Generate empty array and add items in random order

```
private static int[] Shuffle(int n) {
    var a = new int[n];
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        var j = random.Next(0, i);
        Swap(a, i, j);
    }
    return a;
}

private static void Swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    var temp = i;
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

I'm not fully persuaded about the randomness of solution # 2. Are there better ways of achieving the solution? I'm assuming that whatever approach is taken the solution can only be produced in linear time. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: More glaring is that solution 2 will always return the same array.

Comment: @ratchetfreak...mmm...that's not what I observed when running it...

Comment: Geh, method nameing tripped me up, I missed the `temp=i` in swap which makes it "not a swap".

Comment: Name is not as good. I was just tweaking solution # 1 so I kept the method names.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the inside out version of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm)

In C# it would look like:

```
private static int[] Shuffle(int n) 
{
    var random = new Random();
    var result = new int[n];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        var j = random.Next(0, i + 1);
        if (i != j) 
        {
            result[i] = result[j];
        }
        result[j] = i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's good because you create and shuffle your array at the same time using a well known shuffle.

You'd want to reuse the same `Random` instance though.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the most terse way to do this.

To break this down, `Enumerable.Range` creates an ordered array. Then, `OrderBy` uses a random key generated by the random number generator. This key is associated with each cell in the `int[]`. This means that the `OrderBy` will reshuffle the array based on this random key and voila: a random array of `n` numbers.

```
public static int[] Shuffle(int n)
    {
        var randomGenerator = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, n).OrderBy(x => randomGenerator.Next()).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

naming in solution 2 is rather bad your swap doesn't actually swap but also assigns i to the empty spot first.

You should make this explicit:

```
private static int[] Shuffle(int n) {
    var a = new int[n];
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        a[i] = i; //assign first
        var j = random.Next(0, i + 1);
        Swap(a, i, j);
    }
    return a;
}

//actual swap again.
private static void Swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    var temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

After inlining the swap and forwarding the assigns this becomes:

```
private static int[] Shuffle(int n) {
    var a = new int[n];
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        var j = random.Next(0, i + 1);
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = i;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `i+1` or you'll never get 0 in index 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an another way:

```
int[] GetRandomizedArray(int n)
{
    return GetRandomizedEnumerable(n).ToArray();
}

IEnumerable<int> GetRandomizedEnumerable(int n)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var l = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToList();
    foreach (var r in Enumerable.Range(0, n).Reverse().Select(i => random.Next(i + 1)))
    {
        yield return l[r];
        l.RemoveAt(r);
    }
}
```

A bit less performant, but easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler ways to achieve this. For example:

```
new int[N].Select((s,i) => i + 1).OrderBy(o=> Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
```

Or

```
Enumerable.Range(0,N).Select(.....
```

This will be for a sequence of 1 to 10 with a randomised order

Comment: OP is asking for a better solution. If this is not a better solution, the onus is on OP or commenter like you to underline why this is not a better solution.
OP considers his solution to be not ideal and is asking for a better solution
That 10 is N is obvoius.